# Get table data using $http in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and am trying to load table data from controller.Data is coming but its not displaying in table.What went wrong here?

```
<script>
    var app=angular
                .module("intranet_App", [])
                .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                    $http.post("/Admin/getRolesList")
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                        $scope.List= response.data;
                       console.log(List)
                    });
                })
</script>
```

Here `/Admin/getRolesList` is my controller name and path.
html:

```
          <tbody >
                <tr ng-repeat="x in List">
                    <td>{{List.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{List.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

This is my response format:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have getting the values from like `Array.value`, it should like `Array[0].value`. So Use `x.Id` instead of `List.Id`,

```
             <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in List">
                    <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: thanks man.working :-) one doubt, what is `x`  here ?we can use anything instead of x right? If I want 1,2,3... in the place of id means ..how to use for loop here?

Comment: here, `x` is object name of the expression. more details : https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
  //use track by for performance optimization..
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in List track by $index">
                <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{x.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Please refer this for more understanding https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes